# Navigate to the right view from cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have this code to navigate from my tableview to another tableview. But it doesnt navigate to the right tableview. It seems that it creates another view that it navigates to and not the one on my storyboard that I want to go to.
Is this because I create an object?

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{

    ValjKupongViewController *vk = [[ValjKupongViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vk  animated:YES];
}
```

How can I write this the right way so that I navigate to my view in storyboard that have the class ValjKupongViewController?

Very grateful for help!

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"My Custom Segue" sender: self];
}
```

In your StoryBoard

**Step 1** `Ctrl` and `Drag` the mouse from the 
`View Controller` on the left to the `View Controller` on the right.

`View Controller` on the `left` = The View Controller you are transitioning `FROM`.

`View Controller` on the `right` = The View Controller you are transitioning `TO`.

**Step 2** Select `push` as the type of `Segue`

[image]

**Step 3** Now your View Controllers will have the Segue between them (as seen below)

[image]

**Step 4** You need to name the Segue to be able to identify it.Click on the Segue, then go to the attributes inspector and set the `Identifier`. (In the example it is set to `My Custom Segue`.
Make sure this is the same as in the code above.

i.e. `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"My Custom Segue" sender: self];`

[image]

> Is this because I create an object?

Yes you are allocating and initialising a `ValjKupongViewController` object each time `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. With this line of code

`ValjKupongViewController *vk = [[ValjKupongViewController alloc]init];`

You then transition to it with this line 
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vk  animated:YES];`